# Can not cast a spinner position

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I have this class

```
   public class MasterData {
        public long id;
        public String name;

        @Expose(deserialize = true, serialize = false)
        public String type;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    public String getType() {
    return type;
}

 public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
 }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

In my `Activity` I have an `spinner` loaded with `String` values, when the user select one item on the `spinner` I would like to cast the item to my model, `getSelectedItem()` return an `object`, so what I do is:

```
 MasterData md = (MasterData) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

The adapter for the spinner is :

```
 ArrayAdapter spinnerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(spinner.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.toArray(new MasterData[list.size()]));
```

It works well on Huawei but on Samsung I am getting this error:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot
>   be cast to es.miapp.comapny.data.master.model.MasterData

Any idea about what I can do in order to cast a String spinner item to MasterData class?

Comment: `md.setName(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); `

Comment: set spinner adapter of MasterData type list.

Comment: Do you create this spinner by list of MasterData?

Comment: Yes I did ;  ArrayAdapter spinnerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(spinner.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.toArray(new MasterData[list.size()]));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` 
Suppose you have a list, So

```
MasterData md =  list.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```